# How to get a circular frameless window like new hangout widget with Chrome Apps

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am trying to build a chrome application that has a similar widget like the new google hangout on desktops. I have done some reading on frameless borders and downloaded some chrome app samples but none really give a function that allows you to tweak the shape of the frame.

I would really appreciate a solution. Java makes this possible this by allowing you to create a Graphics2D  and setting the window frame of the JFrame to that shape. looks something like this.

```
/*
 * Creates new form Widget
 */
public Widget() {
    //initComponents();
    super("Widget");
    initComponents();
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            Ellipse2D frame = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), getWidth());
            setShape(frame);

        }
    });
}
```

I am hoping to get this similar feature in chrome apps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Package Apps : How to make transparent rounded background like google hangout app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804315/google-chrome-package-apps-how-to-make-transparent-rounded-background-like-goo)

Answer (score 1):

The design doc is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BwU__X2WEayBwa2Su0o4FYrGSqlqcC5q8lQigfTCYCI/edit#

It seems like this feature is still whitelisted to the Hangouts app.

Comment: Thank You very insightful stuff. Though it is under development, I believe I can still use it right? or I have to wait till it is updated in the chromeAPI?

Comment: I read the document but I want to know if anyone has used it for his chrome app before?