# Chrome App: How to create a hovering circle icon like google hangout app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying show a hovering circular icon on user desktop just like Google hangout application do as shown in screens shot below:

[image]

There is a 1 year old question that is saying that its not possible.
    [Stackover flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804315/google-chrome-package-apps-how-to-make-transparent-rounded-background-like-goo)

Is there a workaround or a setting that can be done to achieve the desired task. For an example in Chrome extensions you can show the PANELS by enabling a specific property at [chrome://flags/#enable-panels](http://chrome://flags/#enable-panels)

**Reason Behind the task**

I am developing a **toDo capture tool** and its necessary for me to make my app available as easily as possible so a hovering icon will be good option. All ideas are welcome, please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

Try using experimental extension APIs

> Experimental Extension APIs Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS
>   Enables experimental extension APIs. Note that the extension gallery doesn't allow you to upload extensions that use experimental APIs. #extension-apis

According to [This issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=338155) it should work.